# What happen if the Task is canceled before the thread pool try to execute the code?

Tags: c#, .net

Let's say we have the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
   CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
   Task<Int32> t = Task.Run(() => Sum(cts.Token, 1000000000), cts.Token);
   cts.Cancel();
   ...
}

static Int32 Sum(CancellationToken ct, Int32 n) {
   ...// long operation
}
```

From my understanding, `Task.Run(() => SomeFunction());` schedules the task, and when it is the turn to run the task, the thread pool will create a worker thread to execute the task's contaning code (SomeFunction).

But what if I cancel the task, when the thread pool retrieve the task from the queue, will the thread pool know that it doesn't need to spawn a worker thread to execute the task? or it will still spawn a worker thread first then put this thread's state to canceled? if it is latter, it sounds inefficient, because it is not even nescessary to create a thread.

Comment: The cancellation token passed to the `Run` method is *explicitly* there to allow cancellation before the task starts. Whether and if you've also passed the token *into* the task to allow cancellation *during* its activity is irrelevant to that `Run` call.

Comment: You'll get a lot more **practical** problems solved if you don't assume that the framework developers made bad decisions.

Answer (score 1):

> But what if I cancel the task, when the thread pool retrieve the task from the queue, will the thread pool know

Yes, that's the entire purpose of that parameter on the `Run` method (overloads that accept such a parameter). Once the task has started, that particular reference to a `CancellationToken` is never again considered.

> that it doesn't need to spawn a worker thread to execute the task?

Not exactly. Remember, in the general case, the thread *pool* is passing tasks to *already running threads*. That's why we pool in the first place, to amortise the cost of thread startup.

It's true that if threads aren't returning to the pool often enough to pick up more work that more worker threads will be spawned but that's more a consequence of the pool not currently running with the "right" number of threads (e.g. during startup or a change in workload) and/or long running tasks unsuited to the thread pool being pushed into it.